# Would a Tavern Brawler's improvised weapons qualify for the buffs from the Dual Wielding feat and Two-Weapon Fighting style?

Tags: dnd-5e, improvised-weaponry

If I have the Tavern Brawler feat, giving me proficiency with improvised weapons, does the Dual Wielder feat give me +1 AC whenever I'm wielding two of anything that I'm using as a weapon, like for example two dead goblins?

Also, if that works, would the Two-Weapon Fighting style from Fighter class give me the +Strength bonus to damage with my off-hand goblin?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Interesting, yet Rubiksmoose's answer in this question suggests otherwise, that the dead goblin becomes a melee weapon only for the duration of the attack. So, the answer might be more nuanced. Also, it does the link you give does not address the two-weapon fighting style. Maybe that ought to be a separate question? @IronWaffleMan.

Comment: Yeah I did see that question, but it involved a shield, which I'm not planning on using.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I don't believe this duplication mark is correct. I have now updated the title of the post in question to more accurately reflect its content. It is specifically about stacking shield AC with Dual Wielding AC from using a shield as a weapon. This post is much more general.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan while not directly related, you might find my [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/197374/64161) in the other thread relevant to your question, as it was aimed at the broader title the post initially had. TLDR - ask your DM, but IMO RAI both TWF and DW should work with improvised goblin-weapons.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan I feel like I'm missing a step as to how that distinction matters, but editing in an explanation of why the linked question doesn't answers yours would be good (and probably be sufficient for it to not be a dupe).